# Using and Returning Realm Objects instead of static Array Objects

Tags: swift, realm

**Updated with answer for others** If you are having this problem...

**Problem** I want to use Realm Objects rather than a static array inside a function to return an object output.

**Solution** you need to set up an Object instead of a struct....

e.g.

this :

```
class WorkoutGeneratorObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var maxReps = 0

    convenience init(name: String, maxReps: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.maxReps = maxReps
    }
```

not this :

```
struct WorkoutExercise : Hashable, Equatable{

let name : String
let reps : Int
var hashValue: Int {
    return name.hashValue
}

static func == (lhs: WorkoutExercise, rhs: WorkoutExercise) -> Bool {
    return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

then format the return of the function like this, **within the class object** :

```
class WorkoutGeneratorObject: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var maxReps = 0

    convenience init(name: String, maxReps: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.maxReps = maxReps
    }

    func generateExercise() -> WorkoutExercise {
        return WorkoutExercise(
            name: name,
            reps: Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxReps)))
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in functions elsewhere in your code like this :

```
struct WorkoutGenerator {

// This is the "pool" of exercises from
// which it generates a workout (similar to your
// `exerciseBankArray`)
let realmExercisePool = realm.objects(WorkoutGeneratorObject.self)
let exercisePool: [WorkoutExerciseGenerator]

// Min and max amount of workouts
let minCount: Int
let maxCount: Int

// Generates a workout from the generator
func generate() -> Workout {

    let amount = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxCount - minCount))) + minCount
    let myExercises : [WorkoutExercise] = (0..<amount).map { _ in
        // Selects an exercise generator at random
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(exercisePool.count)))
        // Generates a random workout exercise from this generator

        return realmExercisePool[index].generateExercise()
    }

    return Workout(workoutExercises: myExercises)

}
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: it is 'return realmExercisePool[index].generateWorkout() - will update question also

Comment: I think there's a typo in your code: `let realmExercisePool = [realm.objects(WorkoutGeneratorObject.self)]` this should be `let realmExercisePool = realm.objects(WorkoutExercise.self)`, since first of all there's no `WorkoutGeneratorObject` class defined in your question and second of all, from the information in your question, it seems to me that `realmExercisePool` should contain exercises and not generators.

Comment: yes you are right, the realmExercisePool contains exercises but they are created as a result of the 'generateWorkout' function (the output is a number of exercises with a name and certain amount of reps, that are determined by the "WorkoutGeneratorObjects" which define the name and a 'maximum' number of reps (if that makes sense) - I was hesitant to post my whole code file but I will update because it will probably help with context

Comment: @DávidPásztor have updated question - if you've got any ideas on the above that would be much appreciated :-)